# map the colors of a boxplot with values using seaborn

Tags: pandas, dataframe, charts, colors, seaborn

I am making a boxplot with seaborn base on some values , and i want to map the colors with some other colors i am doing this :

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,12))
sns.boxplot(y='name',x='value',data=df,showfliers=False,orient="h")
```

the result is boxplots with random colors i want the colors to be defined according to a value of a third column in the dataframe. The only thing i could find it the use of "HUE" but it is dividing the data on more boxplots and it is not what i want to do

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed specify the color with `hue`:

```
sns.boxplot(x='name', y='value', data=df
            hue='name',     # same with `x`
            palette={'A':'r','B':'b'},  # specify color
            )
```